# Mostrar solo algunos datos en el campo de una tabla con PHP y MySql

Tags: mysql, php7

Me ha surgido una duda que espero podáis orientarme en como hacerlo.

Tengo una tabla en la que se muestran todos los datos de esa tabla en la página correspondiente con *PHP* y *MySql* para conectarse a la base de datos.

Dependiendo del usuario que esté viendo la tabla quisiera que se mostrasen unos datos y otros no. Es decir, todos los usuarios en todos los datos de todos los campos de la tabla y lo que me gustaría conseguir es que en uno de los campos de la tabla, que el usuario vea solo lo que corresponde a su usuario, pero el resto de campos siga igual, es decir que se vea todo.

Hay un campo en la tabla que se llama ZV y ese campo es igual que su usuario de login, por lo que si quiero que solo vean lo suyo en la tabla hago este *SELECT*:

```
$datos = $mysqli->query("select * from contratospendientes join usuarios on usuarios.usuario = contratospendientes.zv where  id = '$idusuario' " );
```

Que es como Ahora mismo lo tengo puesto para que los usuarios vean todos los datos de la tabla, no solo lo de ese usuario en concreto.

```
$datos = $mysqli->query("select * from contratospendientes)
```

Mi duda es, si quisiera que en uno de los campos se muestren solo datos que sean de ese usuario en concreto y si no que salga en blanco, tendría que poner un *SELECT* y un *if*, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

El campo sería este `<td align="center"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrEscal; ?></td>` y este *anexoDistrBonus*; que son los dos antepenúltimos.

Os pongo el código en *PHP* de esa tabla para que veáis lo que digo.

Espero que podáis orientarme en esta duda.

```
 <?php  
  $datos = $mysqli->query("select * from contratospendientes" );
 ?>
 <?php if($datos->num_rows>0):?>
           
      <!---Muestra resultados en tabla--->   
    <p>Resultados <?php echo $datos->num_rows; ?></p>
    <div class="row table-responsive" style="width:100%">
    <table class="table display table-striped table-bordered" id="mitabla" border="1" style="width:100%">

        <thead style='background-color:#A0A0A0;'>
     
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Business Partner</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Nombre completo</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Abreviatura (Kzz)</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Zona de Ventas</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Ramo  </th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Tipo Partner</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Tipo Contrato</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Fecha Env&#237;o</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Fecha Recepci&#243;n</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Estado    </th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Contador &#40;Fechas&#41;</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#FC0A0A>Escalado Distrib.</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#FC0A0A>&#37; Bonus Distrib.</th>
        <th align="center"><font color=#070707>Ver Registro</th>
    
    </thead>
     
    <?php while($d= $datos->fetch_object()):?>

        <tr>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $d->noCliente; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->nombreCliente;?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->solicitante;?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $d->zv; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $d->ramo; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->tipoPartner;?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $d->tipoContr ; ?></td>
        <td align="right"><?php echo $d->fechaEnvio; ?></td>
        
        <td align="right"><?php echo $d->fechaRecep; ?></td>
        <td align="center"
        <?php
        if($d->fechaRecep == 0) {
            $d->estado = 'PENDIENTE';
            echo  'style="background-color: red; color: white;"';
        } else {
             $d->estado = 'RECIBIDO';
            echo  'style="background-color: green; color: white;"';
           
        }
        ?>><?php echo $d->estado; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
        <?php  if  ($d->fechaEnvio == 0){     
              echo $d->contador= 0;
                    }elseif ($d->fechaRecep == 0){              
                                $datetime1 = date_create($d->fechaActual);
                                $datetime2 = date_create($d->fechaEnvio);
                                $contador = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
                                $differenceFormat = '%a';
                                echo $contador->format($differenceFormat);
                    }else{
                                $datetime2 = date_create($d->fechaEnvio);
                                $datetime3 = date_create($d->fechaRecep);
                                $contador = date_diff($datetime2, $datetime3);
                                $differenceFormat = '%a';
                                echo $contador->format($differenceFormat);
                    } 
        ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrEscal; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrBonus; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="ver.php?id_contrpen=<?php echo $d-> id_contrpen; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
    <?php else:?>
    <h3>No hay Datos</h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Ver solo los datos del campo anexoDistrEscal de ese usuario, pero salen todos.

```html
<td align="center"><?php $query = "select anexoDistrEscal from contratospendientes
                     join usuarios on usuarios.usuario = contratospendientes.zv                        where id = '$idusuario' ";
                            if($result=$mysqli->query($query)){
                                echo $d-> anexoDistrEscal;} ?>
</td>
```

Comment: La pregunta es confusa. ¿Te refieres a algo así como *Roles*, donde un tipo de usuario puede ver una determinada información y otra no? Describe esto *"Dependiendo del usuario que esté viendo la tabla quisiera que se mostrasen unos datos y otros no. Es decir, todos los usuarios en todos los datos de todos los campos de la tabla y lo que me gustaría conseguir es que en uno de los campos de la tabla, que el usuario vea solo lo que corresponde a su usuario, pero el resto de campos siga igual, es decir que se vea todo."* con el método de depuración del *Patito de Goma* y quizá podamos entender.

Comment: Lo del *Patito de goma* no es broma. Si no has oído hablar de este método, [aquí tienes explicado en qué consiste](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma). Muchas veces el problema más grande es no saber explicar el problema, y explicando el problema encuentras la solución porque te diste cuenta del error en ese proceso.

Answer (score 0):

podrías utilizar una variable de sesión la cual recoja durante todo el programa el usuario el cual esta iniciado en la sesión y hacer una comprobación donde dependiendo de si el usuario es por ejemplo 'Manolo' le dejes ver el campo de 'Estado' y si se llama 'María' le deje ver el de 'Fecha de envío'.

Sería utilizar en php la variable $_SESSION e ir pasandola por todas tus páginas al inicio del código. Luego más tarde donde quieras controlar la visualización utilizar un If el cual iguales el usuario con el de la base de datos.

EN cambio, si lo que quieres es controlar que sea por tipo de usuario, por ejemplo si es Admin o Cliente tendrías que hacer algo parecido, solo que en vez de coger solo la variable sesión una vez en el if coger el tipo de usuario con la variable.

No sé si me he explicado bien si necesitas cualquier cosa no dudes en decirme

Comment: Eso es, es una forma de controlar que la sesión está iniciada, con ella también podrías controlar el log out si quieres que el usuario pueda cerrar sesión.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra respuesta. La variable de $_SESSION la utilizo en todas las páginas a las que accede el usuario. Lo que intento es que en esa tabla que vea todo lo que hay que es info de varios usuarios, pero en uno de los campos de la tabla que vea sólo lo que corresponde a ese usuario y lo de los demás que no lo vea o que esté en blanco. Espero que me hayais entendido. Se trata solo de determinda info de uno de los campos, no de toda la tabla

Comment: Pues con esa variable sesión, controlas que te muestre la descripción de ese usuario por ejemplo. Sería algo como buscar en la base de datos mediante una consulta integrada en PHP con esa variable de sesión y una vez encontrado mostrar los datos de ese usuario.

Comment: Sería algo así como hacer una  consulta nueva solo con ese campo y la condición que corresponda que en este caso seria donde el usuario sea el que tiene la sesión iniciada, y luego hacer un condicional,  donde se pregunte por el resultado de la consulta